# A LinearLayout and a ListView be in one view?

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, android-listview

Example:

Main LinearLayout

|Sub LinearLayout|ListView        |

ListView has a set of names, which change the sub linear layout's content.
Now I have the sub LL in my main LL. How do I add the ListView properly, using an

```
arraylist<string> ar
```

But I don't know how to properly use the list adapter.

One other question: can I update the listview contents with a thread every few seconds?

Comment: yea its possible to order items like that, your linearlayout should have horizontal orientation i believe so when you add listview it will go next to it. Also you can refresh listview with notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: 1. Yes, they can; 2. Yes, you can. Any more questions?

Comment: Yes, you can have a `ListView` in a `LinearLayout`. The problem arises with `ScrollView` as its "incompatible" or I may say, doesnt behave properly with some other Views. Just to let you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one to update every few second.

```
handler=new Handler();
            final Runnable r = new Runnable()
            {
                public void run() 
                {
                    //Write your code here

                    handler.postDelayed(this, 100);
                }
            };

            handler.postDelayed(r,100);
```